# How to add many UIViews (each with a button within) as subviews to UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying use a loop to add many UIView, each representing an object and contains an UIImage + UILabel returned from a db query, to a UIScrollview. Each UIView has a button inside, which is designed to call the superview to segue to the next UIViewController. However, since I'm allocating these UIViews within a for-loop, the memory doesn't seem to be retained, so the button press always causes a seg-fault.

Since I need to pass the UIImage and UILabel stored in the UIView to the controller I'm segueway-ing into, what's the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

Parent view:

//this is called from a for loop

```
IndividualObjectViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"smallObjectSubView"];
controller.delegate = self;    
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(105*column+5, 125*row+45, 100, 120);
[self.objectScrollView addSubview:controller.view];
```

object view:

- (IBAction)objectButton:(id)sender {
  }

I left the IBAction completely empty for debug, but it looks like as soon as I connect this action with the storyboard button, I get program received signal: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: this sounds like a NavigationController with a ListView? Why not use what apple already gives you?

Comment: It is indeed a NavigationController, but I'm not having much luck on finding info on UIListView. Can you point me to more info on that? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: May be you just using wrong selector for button: @sector(press) instead of @selector(press:). Provide you code, please.

Comment: I'm familiar with the UITableView, but my current use case calls for a 3 column wide of UIViews to be added to the UIScrollView, which means that each entry doesn't have its own row.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't retain `controller`, it will be deallocated at the end of the current pass through the run loop (even though you are using its view).

You should be storing all of the `IndividualObjectViewController` instances in an `NSMutableArray` or an `NSMutableDictionary`.  Those containers retain the objects you store in them.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Will this create problems in memory if I'm loading a lot of these views (say 30+)? Is this the approach used by UITableView?

Comment: Just tried this by adding a @property (Strong) NSMutableArray in the parent controller and adding each object controller to it, the result is the same EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: `UITableView` doesn't require that each cell have its own `UIViewController`, which is what you are effectively doing.